# What's the name of the job that is about "typing really fast to write instant subtitles"

Tags: single-word-requests

> Tom is a fast typist. He's a [...]. He watches talk shows and transcribes each sentence under five seconds. Although five seconds might sound disturbing, the viewers are not annoyed by little delays.

What is Tom's job called?

Comment: There is also "stenotyper" -- a person who operates a Stenotype machine.  These were originally used in courtrooms to replace the use of shorthand to record the trial, then were adapted (using a computer to convert from phonetics to the natural language) to provide instantaneous closed captions.  I assume the technology has moved on, but it's likely still derived from this origin.

Comment: @HotLicks -- I had always heard this job as "_stenographer_" rather than "_stenotyper_", but perhaps that's a regional difference?

Comment: @RogerSinasohn - "Stenographer" is what it was when the person used a pencil and steno pad.  A "stenotyper" uses a Stenotype machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Subtitles* are not the same thing as *closed captions*. With the latter, text is simply used for people who can't hear what is being spoken. However, the former are used for people who can't understand the language that is being spoken.

Therefore, a good "subtitler" combines elements of a [**translator**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translator) *and* a [**transcriptionist**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transcriptionist). (Both links go to Merriam-Webster definitions, the former to the verb *translate*.)

[Speechpad](https://www.speechpad.com/blog/transcription-translation-subtitling), a company that provides these services, describes it in this way:

> It is important to understand that subtitling is not related to closed captioning, which is the text of a video aimed toward the audience of the deaf and hard of hearing. Closed Captioning is more specific in nature than subtitling because it includes references as to who is speaking and relevant sounds such as a doorbell, dog barking, or music being played. These are generally displayed in a black box near the bottom of the screen.
>
> In contrast, subtitles are targeted toward individuals who can hear but may not be able to understand what is being said, either because the dialogue is garbled and unable to be understood, contains dialogue in a foreign language, or is being targeted toward a foreign audience. For all of these reasons, it is of vital importance that the transcription and/or the translation be precise and accurate. Otherwise, the subtitles will not properly reflect the dialogue of the video, and the message that the video is trying to convey will not be understood by the target audience.

Because of the need for both transcription *and* (accurate) translation, it's extremely unlikely that anybody who produces *subtitles* would ever do so with such rapidity as described in the question. Nor, if it is meant to capture audio cues, would *closed captioning* be practised with such rapidity.

However, some TV shows do show "instant" (or real-time) transcriptions of speech. That would be a specific role of a **transcriptionist**. And what is produced would not be *subtitles* but *closed captions* without any audio cues.

---

**Update**: I originally claimed that "subtitler" was not a word, but a comment suggested otherwise. I was sure that I had checked this in [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subtitler), but, obviously, I must not have. (Or perhaps I had mistyped it.) It is still not found in the online versions of Merriam-Webster or Collins.

It seems to not be a well-used word, and it still wouldn't be the word used to describe the job outlined in the question, but I needed to correct this false claim.

Comment: *Therefore, a good "subtitler" (that is not a word)* - of course it's a word!

Comment: @JamesRandom Mea culpa! I checked various dictionaries again and discovered my mistake with Oxford. I've retracted my statement.